# How can I use Grails Searchable (lucene) to perform the equivalent Criteria query the most efficient way

Tags: grails, lucene, searchable

I am searching against a single Domain class, but also trying to allow wildcard queries against 2 String fields,  I understand wildcard (first character) queries are supposed to be inefficient however if only against 2 fields, then perhaps that's not so significant.

I'm trying to accomplish what would be the follow as a criteria query..

```
MyDomain.createCriteria().list {
  and {
    notEqual('deleted',true)
    or {
      ilike('field1','%' + searchText + '%')
      ilike('field2','%' + searchText + '%')
    }
  } 
}
```

Any suggestions much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Since leading wildcards generally require a full scan of the index for that field, it is indeed quite significant.  Leading wildcards almost universally should be replaced with better analysis at index time.

Comment: How do you index your text fields? what kind of text do you want to look for?

Comment: The users are wanting almost google style search freedom, so if they can't remember the first part of someones name, or the trailing end of someones name it should give results.   so Kowalski, owalski, kowalsk  should all include Kowalski in the results.

Comment: The indexing is automatically handled via the Grails Searchable plugin.

Comment: is the searchText a single term or multiple words?

Comment: typically single term.

Answer (score 0):

a lucene query would look like:

```
-deleted:true +(field1:searchText field2:searchText)
```

Comment: Shouldn't this include OR and '*' wildcards to accomplish the same behaviour as the criteria?

Comment: `OR` is the default clause and can be ommitted. leading wildcard search is extremly expensive in terms of lucene and should be avoided.